# Select event is not working in AjaxData GridView

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have an issue with my ajax gridview, I want to get values from label inside my ajax but it's returning null. below is my gridview:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="myModal" class="modal" style="display: none">
                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span onclick="CloseMyDiv();" id="closeSpan" class="close">×</span>
                    <br />
                    <div class="modal-body">

                    <AjaxData:GridView id="grdvPriorApproval" runat="server" RowCommandEvent="extractFunction">

                        <Columns>
                         <AjaxData:GridViewTemplateColumn  HeaderText="ClaimhId" SortField="ClaimhId" Visible="False" >
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtClaimhID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ClaimhId") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate >
                                <asp:Label ClientIDMode="Static" ID="lblClaimhID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ClaimhId") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </AjaxData:GridViewTemplateColumn>

                       <AjaxData:GridViewTemplateColumn  HeaderText="ApprovalTypeId" SortField="ClaimhId" Visible="False" >
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="txtApprovalTypeId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ApprovaltypeID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate >
                                <asp:Label ClientIDMode="Static" ID="lblApprovalTypeId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ApprovaltypeID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </AjaxData:GridViewTemplateColumn>

                        <AjaxData:GridViewBoundColumn ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Reference" DataField="Reference" SortField="Reference" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100px" />
                           <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </AjaxData:GridViewBoundColumn>

                        <AjaxData:GridViewBoundColumn ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Patient #" DataField="MemberId" SortField="MemberId" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100px" />
                           <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </AjaxData:GridViewBoundColumn>

                        <AjaxData:GridViewBoundColumn ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Patient Name" DataField="MemberName" SortField="MemberName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100px" />
                           <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </AjaxData:GridViewBoundColumn>

                        <AjaxData:GridViewBoundColumn ReadOnly="true"  HeaderText="Remarks" DataField="Remark" SortField="Remark" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100px" />
                           <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </AjaxData:GridViewBoundColumn>

                        <AjaxData:GridViewBoundColumn ReadOnly="true"  HeaderText="Valid Untill" DataField="ValidUntill" SortField="ValidUntill" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100px" />
                           <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </AjaxData:GridViewBoundColumn>

                        <AjaxData:GridViewCommandColumn ControlStyle-Font-Bold="true" ControlStyle-ForeColor="#f2fae5"
                                    ControlStyle-BackColor="#6c9815" ButtonType="Button"  SelectText="Extract" ShowSelectButton="True">
                        </AjaxData:GridViewCommandColumn>
                       <%--<AjaxData:GridViewButtonColumn CommandName ="extract" ControlStyle-Font-Bold="true" ControlStyle-ForeColor ="black" Text="Extract" Visible="true"  >
                       </AjaxData:GridViewButtonColumn>--%>
                        </Columns>
                        </AjaxData:GridView> 
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

      </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And this is my javascript function:

```
 function extractFunction(sender,e) {
      var index = e.get_row().get_rowIndex();
      var gridView = $find('<%= grdvPriorApproval.ClientID %>');
      var row = gridView._rows[index].findControl('lblClaimhID').value;
     __doPostBack('CustomPostBack', row);
    }
```

Index value is 0 and row value is null. 
1- I tried to change RowCommandEvent to SelectedIndexChangedEvent but that will create an issue on finding index (it will return an error).
2- In postback event I tried to get the selected row and values in this way:

CType(Me.grdvPriorApproval.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblApprovalTypeId"), Label).Text

but I got an error [under selectedRow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTd5j.png)

Any help with my first Ajaxdata gridview is appreciated

Comment: I tried to change my grid now to telegrid, but I did not get data from my webservice. So I prefer to use ajaxData, please Help, I'm still stuck in this issue since 3 days ! Thank you